# create file json with multi array from a external json file

Tags: php, json

I made a search in stackoverflow, really I found a lot of threads about multi arrays, but no one can help me, for that reason a new thread, maybe someone can help me find a solution for my problem.

What I want is create a Json file getting values from a external json file.

Example what I want:

```
{
 "day":[[1522108800000,6305.5],[1522195200000,6440.7]],
 "month":[[1522108800000,6305.5],[1522195200000,6440.7]]
}
```

I tried my code, but only can get values from 1 json file, and not from both json files.
Please see and let me know if you can help / suggest something.

```
// Array Min    
$json_min = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=5&e=kraken");

// Array Day
$json_day = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=5&e=kraken");

$array_min = json_decode($json_min, true);
$array_day = json_decode($json_day, true);

$array = array (
        'day' => array (),
        'month' => array (),
    );

foreach($array_min['Data'] as $key)
{
    $close_min   = $key['close'];
    $time_min    = $key['time'];
    $time_min    = $time_min *1000;

    $close_day   = $key2['close'];
    $time_day    = $key2['time'];
    $time_day    = $time_day *1000;

    $array['day'][] = [$time_min, $close_min];
    $array['month'][] = [$time_day, $close_day];

}

$json_data   = json_encode($array);
file_put_contents( 'json/history.json', $json_data);
```

Comment: Are you using PHP ?

Comment: Pro-Tip: PHP is not HTML.

Comment: `$array_min` is unused. `$array_day` is unused. `$array['Data']` is not set. `$key2` doesn't exist.

Comment: @executable yes PHP

Comment: @melpomene Yes, exactly my problem how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes were primarily: `$array['Data']` does not exist, so the foreach will never run, and also you did not have any $key2 defined to read from the second array. You need to loop over each input array separately.

The code below will do it quite neatly.

It's possible to do it more verbosely with two totally independent loops (one for each input), but: since you wish to perform the same operations on both inputs, it's possible to do it in less code by placing both input arrays into a wrapper array, and giving it the entries keys which match the keys in the output array:

```
// Array Min    
$json_min = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=5&e=kraken");

// Array Day
$json_day = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=5&e=kraken");

//place both inputs into an array labelled "day" and "month", ready for processing
$input = array("day" => json_decode($json_min, true), "month" => json_decode($json_day, true));

$output = array (
  "day" => array(),
  "month" => array(),
);

//loop through each entry in the input array
foreach ($input as $key => $data)
{
  //loop through the actual data and process it
  foreach($data['Data'] as $datakey => $value)
  {
    $close   = $value['close'];
    $time    = $value['time'] * 1000;
    //output the data to an array in "output" with the same key as the input array we're currently processing
    $output[$key][] = [$time, $close];
  }
}

$json_data   = json_encode($output);
file_put_contents( 'json/history.json', $json_data);
```

See here: https://eval.in/1027493 for a working demo.